# All proper subgroups cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I am in the course of writing a proof for a result and it turned out that it works for all finite groups whose all proper subgroups are cyclic. Does anyone know any interesting characteristics of such groups?

Examples include: all cyclic groups, $C_p \times C_p$ for any prime $p$, $S_3$, $Q_8$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253777/finite-groups-in-which-all-proper-subgroups-are-cyclic (First hit on the obvious google search...)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shaun, for some reason it didn't appear in my search, neither did it appear in the suggestions of questions already asked.

Comment: Just in case that helps, I searched for "groups with all proper subgroups cyclic" (without the quotes) and the MO question is the first hit (for me).